# Strange ESP8266 response

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am currently playing with esp8266. It is connected to arduino via software COM port. Arduino is sending AT commands and esp is sending responses back.
The problem is that small responses look absolutely normal but longer ones are kind of damaged. First I thought this was because poor wiring but problem remained after correcting it. Also long responses are always corrupted after certain point and there is not absolute garbage but something looking slightly like correct thing:

```
AT+CWLAP

+CWLAP:(3,"MGTS_GPON_1936",-81,"94:4a:0c:44:8d:58",0,23,0)
+CWLAP:("::,C"N7:e,Ar8":,C""::,C"-2:0:O-ea,Aa":c,C"5::0LG8,f9):P-9:3Lv8:5,AT68d1
"9":"
458e1
```

```
AT+CWLAP

+CWLAP:(4,"Vikus",-60,"f4:6d:04:a0:ee:36",1,40,0)
+CWLAP:(3,"NURIK":55Ae4,803WM_205)PS,30):_,37,Ae9e13+,s-0e0PR,453LT9":,):_"8:1+,"::,+T"::,+,"5:3
```

```
busy s...

Recv 4 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,166:<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></heaor>r e/
e<<tS
```

After replacing power supply, arduino, esp module and load capacitor things not changed:

```
AT+CIPSTART=
"UDP","time1.google.c⸮Kb⸮⸮⸮j

0,CONNECT



OK

AT+CIPSE
ND=48



OK
> 

Secv 48 cytes


SE
ND OK

+RE⸮⸮⸮⸮"
⸮
```

```
AT+CWLAP


+CWLAP:(3,"NUR
IK",-74,"38:2c:4a:98:85:4f",1,0,0)
+CWLAP:(4,"MGT_P96,4":8b:::
8"18⸮⸮⸮*A⸮B⸮b⸮U⸮⸮͡⸮⸮⸮ʲ⸮⸮%⸮х⸮⸮⸮bkʂb2⸮⸮⸮⸮*⸮颊҂⸮Ҫ⸮b⸮b⸮
Ғ*⸮⸮bb⸮b⸮Jj
+CWLP3"oOK0"7,04:::8a080
⸮*A⸮B⸮b⸮⸮k⸮͉bj⸮b2Ѳ
```

Comment: you use SotwareSerial at 115200 baud?

Comment: @underscore_d probably but I did not know about its existence

Comment: @Juraj yes, that was the problem. I changed esp8266 baud rate and now all responses are correct but random "new lines" appearing everywhere

Comment: do you use println to copy the response to Serial Monitor?

Comment: @Juraj uhm yes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is Arduino's Software serial can't properly work on 115200 baud rate needed to communicate to esp8266. To fix this you have to send command `AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0` to change esp baud rate and after that change SoftwareSerial speed to 9600.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bus clock mismatch or corrupt RAM. Can you replace each side at a time with the same hardware?

Also check out your power supply.

Corruption in long messages also may be the indicator of inadequate load support capacitors.

Comment: Those things can be little buggers some times...

Comment: It become even worse. I updated the question